# Re-assigning numbers to be in order in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, fields-attributes, numbering

I have deleted some unnecessary fields and hence my numbers are now no longer in order. I can't simply use the sequential function for this as the duplicated numbers have to remain duplicated.

I would hence like to reassign the numbers in my attribute field to be in order. For instance, as you refer to my snapshot below, I would like

```
19 to be 1,
21 to be 2,
23 to be 3,
24 to be 4,
25 to be 5,
28 to be 6,
31 to be 7,
......
```

As I have over 500 rows, is there a quick way to reassign these numbers to be in order?

[image]

Comment: You could do this with a global dictionary in a CalculateField code block or with a dictionary in a `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`. Pick one, give it a try, and [Edit] the Question if you have a difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using a Python dictionary, which has already been mentioned in the comments, a SQL ORDER BY clause can also be used with an ArcPy update cursor in such a situation.  For example,

```py
import arcpy

layer = "" # layer name or path to feature class or table
field = "clusternum" # name of field to update
sql_order = f"ORDER BY {field}"
count = 1

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(layer, field, sql_clause=(None, sql_order)) as cur:
    prev_i, = next(cur)
    cur.updateRow([count])
    for i, in cur:
        if i != prev_i:
            prev_i = i
            count += 1
        cur.updateRow([count])
```